# read url link from excel file with C#

Tags: c#, excel-2003

I have the following code:

```
private DataSet GetDataSet(string tableName)
{
    DbCommand cmd = GetConnection().CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT data FROM " + tableName;
    DbDataAdapter da = GetDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "query");

    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["query"];

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[col]);
        }
    }

    return ds;
}
```

is it possible to read url link from excel file?

I have in excel link like:

[PARK](http://somelink)

but when i read from excel i see onl word PARK and no link.

/Regards

Comment: In its current state this post definitely needs a cleaned up code tag for the "private DataSet GetDataSet..." section.

Comment: You need to `Close()` your commands and connections.

Comment: i rebuild my code. Now i close connection but i do not know what will Close() help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OleDB can only read the raw data in the cells.

If you want to read formatting (including hyperlinks), you'll need to use COM Interop to automate Excel or buy a third-party Excel library.

Comment: hmm do you have an example of COM interop or give me link of third-part Excel library. Maybe do you know any opensource?

/regards